# Assets files need to be updated on app upgrade

Tags: android, android-assets

I have a couple asset files stored in the assets folder.

I use AssetManager getAssets and copy those files to an external dir:

```
in = assetManager.open(filename);
File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
String filePath = outFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Then I use the file paths to open the files:

```
    this.mydat = new RandomAccessSteamIn();
    this.mydat.setFile(filePath1);
    this.mydat = new RandomAccessFile(filePath2, "r");
```

to read the binary asset files.

This is my first time deploying an Android app, so I have some questions:

On every app upgrade, I would like to replace the binary files in the assets folder (with newer versions), but keep the file names. Will this be a problem, if every time I detect an app upgrade, I copy the files over again to the external dir?

Is there a better way for achieving this?

Comment: If you copy the assets every time you start the app then you are safe, if you are copying only once then you need a version control system. Reading the new file is no problem, the problem may is what you do with the data readed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it might be bad to re-write the files to external dir again if the files were updated; as a matter of fact I've faced this in multiple use-cases, where the file had to be re-written on the external dir each time an edit has been made to it. So I will suggest one approach I use.

First, in `build.gradle`, I generate an MD5 hash of the file currently in the assets, and I store it as a `resValue` string.

Second (this could happen wherever you need it in your app), I read the hash stored in `resValue` and compare it to the previously stored MD5 hash (I store this in `SharedPreferences`, and this value represents the hash of the asset file before it was updated to a newer version in your case).

Finally, if the hashes don't match, I run the code for reading the file from `AssetManager` and re-writing it on external dir.

This way whenever your file in assets has been modified, it would generate a different hash, and it would directly be read and written on the external dir.